# Align 11 columns on bootstrap, how to deal with missing column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid with 11 columns

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">10</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">11</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that bootstrap works on 12 column grids, therefore the 12th column shows empty. (making the grid look non centered)

I want to center this grid so at the beginning of the grid there will be the space of half a column, and at the end of the grid it will show the other half:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1/2">1/2 blank</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">10</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1/2">1/2 blank</div>
</div>
```

^ thats an example of how I imagine it will work, but unfortunately we dont have 1/2 columns on boostrap.

Comment: You may want to rethink why you are using a framework that defines a 12-column grid if you need 11-column grid (i.e. why not use the right tool for the right job?) - If you still want to use bootstrap, it looks like you are going to have to define those 1/2 columns yourself in your own CSS (you could see their code and learn how they did it for `col-lg-1` and replicate those in your own CSS)

Comment: @ochi Well, we have plenty of other forms in the application, but there is this one grid in one page that happens to have 11 columns, and it doesnt look centered.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a half-size column to add into a supplemental style sheet (You'll want to make sure you account for all of the styling, though):

```
.col-lg-half {
    width: 4.166666665%;
}

.col-lg-half
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-half {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Then, what you are wanting should work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-half">1/2 blank</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">10</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-lg-half">1/2 blank</div>
</div>
```